# Are my calculations wrong?

Tags: rf, frequency, inductance, coil

So I'm trying to make relatively a large square coil antenna that will operate at 125kHz frequency.

The width and height of antenna are 300mm (30cm) and wire diameter is AWG24 (0.51mm) and I'd like to keep number of turns pretty low (under 30).

To calculate inductance I entered antenna parameters to [this](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/tools/rectangle-loop-inductance-calculator/) calculator and came up with inductance value of 0.000731H (with number of turns being 22; width, height=300mm; wire diameter=0.51mm; permeability=1).

I then calculated resonant frequency with [another](http://www.1728.org/resfreq.htm) calculator where I entered the inductance value I got before (0.000731H) and capacitance of 2.2nF. The resulting resonant frequency was 1.2550 Hertz which is only about 0.00125kHz, way below 125khz which I need.

Now to achieve 125kHz I could increase the inductance to 731H by making number of turns equal 22,000 but this idea doesn't seem to be very practical. Does anyone has any suggestions to solve this problem?

Comment: Wouldn't increasing the inductance _lower_ the resonant frequency?

Comment: To increase the resonant frequency you need to decrease the *product* of the inductance and capacitance.  Likely your capacitor is too big, but as your conclusions are backwards your calculation may be wrong.

Comment: Actually it looks like you've just mixed up decimals / prefixes in working with the calculator - how did you get 0.00125kHz ?  What it actually proposes for your sample inductance and capacitance is 125.5 KHz

Comment: @ChrisStratton This is confusing. When I convert 0.1255 MegaHertz into Khz using google I get 125, but 1.255 Hertz to Khz gives me 0.001255? The calculator gives both results though, what's that all about?

Comment: Sometimes it's useful to have a sense of scale and plausibility... a single digit Hz result is just not realistic so is either a user/transcription error a mistake in the web calculator code.

Comment: @ChrisStratton So technically, I could achieve 125khz with those antenna parameters?

Comment: 1kHz = 1000Hz.  So 1Hz = 0.001kHz.  Does that make sense of the 1.255Hz to 0.001255kHz?  1MHz = 1000kHz; hopefully you can apply the math from there.  It's pretty easy to get the prefixes confused; I check my calculations by remembering that each step up is way bigger than the one before, and double-check my numbers as I go along.

Comment: @beginner "When I convert 0.1255 MegaHertz into Khz using google I get 125"; mostly, you get 125 **kHz**. Not Hz, because you asked for it to be converted into kHz.

Comment: Just for a sanity check 1uH and 1uF resonate at 160KHz. So do 10uH and 0.1uF. So do 100uH and 0.01uF.

Answer (score 1):

When I started life as a graduate EE in 1975 we had both slide rulers and HP Calculators and a Nova Minicomputer .

I was introduced to graph paper just like below  which helps save time and quick check any RLC Z Qs,Qp vs f calculation.

How you learn to trust your results comes with experience.   @analogsystemsrf and  I think alike.

"1uH and 1uF resonate at 160KHz" which is also 1 Ohm.

How you choose Q depends on ESR and DCR for series resonance which for high values Qs is almost same as current gain and for Parallel resonance, Qp depends on load Rp and leakage Rc.  So you can choose components with good impedance for desired Q ratios.

Also for inductors a straight wire is 1uH/m for 80:1 length, thickness ratio and 0.5 uH/m for ~6:1 ratio in air but large loops are around 25 x greater than a straight wire self inductance.

[image]